# Response from SoftLayer API has changed

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've been using the SoftLayer APIs successfully for many months, but very recently I've seen what appears to be a change in API responses.

We call Python thus to get networking config details:

rec = fetchDetails(slRecord, hostType, "mask[networkComponents[name,port,primarySubnet[networkVlanId]],networkVlans[id,networkSpace]]")

However, the data returned for networkComponents has changed.

BEFORE
[{'primarySubnet': {'networkVlanId': 308168}, 'maxSpeed': 1000, 'name': 'eth', 'port': 0}, {'primarySubnet': {'networkVlanId': 377724}, 'maxSpeed': 1000, 'name': 'eth', 'port': 1}]

AFTER
[**[],**{'primarySubnet': {'networkVlanId': 308168}, 'name': 'eth', 'port': 0}, {'primarySubnet': {'networkVlanId': 377724}, 'name': 'eth', 'port': 1}, {'name': 'eth', 'port': 2}, {'name': 'eth', 'port': 3}]

Note that the response now contains an empty array as the first entry.

Why has the returning data changed? Have you changed your APIs?

Comment: This might also be bad data that's specific to your account. It'd be helpful to know what SoftLayer service and method fetchDetails() actually calls.

You can keep up with changes to the API that might affect you here: https://softlayer.github.io/

Comment: Please the softlayer's service and method that fetchDetails() is calling